# IIB with Token Generation

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

How to implement Oauth2.0 to request a token and then pass this token to make an API call by HTTP Request Node.

Appreciate your support to help me in this as i am new in IIB

Comment: Please update your question and explain what you have tried already.

Comment: i have a system that need from me to be authenticated by generating a token from the token endpoint then include this token in my request before send him , this flow is what i am trying to do @kimbert

Comment: This is not a good-quality question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you respond again.